# Access control based on URL and a file

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a legacy web application on which I need to set access control based on the URL.

There are only two possibilities: allow from all or allow from my domain.

I believe I can do something like:

```
<Location /app/one-part>
   Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /app/another-part>
   Allow from .foo.tld
</Location>

<Location /app/yet-another-part>
   Allow from .foo.tld
</Location>

....
```

The problem is that this particular application has hundreds of `/app/thinguie` URLs, and I don't want to code them all like I showed above.

Is there a way to do something like

```
<Location from file dom.txt>
   Allow from .foo.tld
</Location>

<Location from file all.txt>
   Allow from All
</Location>
```

and two files with the `/app/whatevers` listed?

thanks in advance.

Oh, by the way, there is no pattern and therefore no regular expression I can use to filter elegantly. :(

Comment: Can you post the real data? I wonder that can we do with a `DirectoryMatch` directive.

Comment: @quanta. In reality it is the same application, and the path represents a database. Some databases need to be accessible from the internet, some do not. There is not much a Match can do.

Comment: If so, check out the @SparX's suggestion. You can use `echo -e "\t..."` to keep formating and also notice that you should use `<Directory>` directive [instead of](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) `<Location>` for access control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache directive "Location" only accepts URL-path or URL as parameter and there is no way to read an external list. What I would suggest is, create a script to generate a custom conf which you can include in your apache conf.

**Example:**

```
[sparx@E1]$ cat file-foo.txt
/my/local
/my/src
/my/local/src
[sparx@E1]$
```

Now create a simple bash script to generate the custom conf.

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in `cat file-foo.txt`
do
echo "<Location $x>"
echo "Allow from .foo.tld"
echo "<\Location>"
done
```

Now execute the script and redirect the output to say, my-foo.conf

```
[sparx@E1]$ ./apgen.sh > my-foo.conf
[sparx@E1]$ cat my-foo.conf
<Location /my/local>
Allow from .foo.tld
<\Location>
<Location /my/src>
Allow from .foo.tld
<\Location>
<Location /my/local/src>
Allow from .foo.tld
<\Location>
[sparx@E1]$
```

Now, the conf file is generated. Verify it and include in your main apache conf.

```
Include "path/to/my-foo.conf"
```

Comment: This was the way chosen.